# Clonezilla image not found

Tags: disk-image, clonezilla

So I cloned a flash drive to image with clonezilla using my /dev/sdc2 mounted as /home/partimag

After the process, I shutdown my PC to do something else only to return unable to find the image I created with Clonezilla.

I remounted my /dev/sdc2 as /mnt expecting to see an image file among the files/folders on that drive but did not.  I mounted it again as /home/partimag but no image file either. It was only after trying a repeat of the process with Clonezilla did I get an indication that the image already was in existence. Clonezilla mounted my /dev/sdc2 as /home/partimag again and it appeared like magic.

In fact if Clonezilla mounts that partition I can see the image file in terminal and nautilus (it appears as a folder in nautilus) even if I terminate Clonezilla.  In fact at this point the image file is the only thing I see at /home/partimag.

If I turn around and unmount /home/partimag and remount that SAME partition (/dev/sdc2) the directory will include the other folders that actually exist on /dev/sdc2.

What's going on here ?